# Hypothetical question about a train

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Imagine a train that comes into a station, stops, and goes back the way it came.  Would it be reasonable to say that this train has "turned around"?  It has changed direction but there is no literal turning involved.

Comment: Trains often have an engine section on both ends - and normally they're both "powered up", regardless of which direction the train is moving. But I imagine there are dual controls in the driver's cab at *each* end, and even though the whole train doesn't "turn around", the driver moves from one end to the other before starting his return journey. So *conceptually / functionally*, the complete system (train + driver) has actually "rotated". Whatever - we don't normally bother about the details. We just say the train turns around at the terminus and goes back to wherever it came from.

Comment: I would say _switch/change direction_. It's really only important to people who find not facing the direction of travel uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't literally "turn around" and come back, but it did figuratively and colloquially "turn around" and come back. So it's both correct and incorrect, depending on the interpretation.

If you wanted to be very exact about the wording, you might avoid the phrase "turn around". "The train want back the other direction.", "The train returned to Hamburg", etc.